# Iterating inputs to calendar.monthrange

Tags: list, for-loop, calendar, iteration

I am using the calendar package to determine the number of days in an arbitrary month and year, based on a list of years and a list of months.  I've tried to pass the year list and month list to calendar.monthrange, but it objects with:

```
'TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= list().
```

So, I used the following code (workable but clumsy).  Is there a more elegant way?

```
# my code
def daysDuringMonth( yyyy, mm ):
    result  = [ ]
    for y in yyyy:
        for m in mm:
            dd = calendar.monthrange( y, m )
            result.append( y, m, dd[ 1 ] )
    return result

# input
yyyy = [ 2013, 2014 ]
mm   = [ 1, 2, 12 ]

# function call
daysDuringMonth( yyyy, mm )

# output
[[2013, 1, 31],
[2013, 2, 28],
[2013, 12, 31],
[2014, 1, 31],
[2014, 2, 28],
[2014, 12, 31]]
```

I can live with solution, but I'd like to know if there's some way to avoid using two nested 'for' loops.

Thank you.

BSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks I figured it out:

```
def daysDuringMonth( yy, mm ):
    result = []    
    [ [ result.append( calendar.monthrange( y, m )[ 1 ] ) for m in mm] for y in yy ]        
    return result
```

where yy and mm are lists.